# how: local directory structure best practice + have local directory structure match web host structure?

Tags: php, apache

Here is my (probably very silly) newbie method of working on projects.

I have a directory C:\websites\ and I keep separate folders for all my sites in there.

Whenever I want to work on one of those sites, I copy and paste the files for that site from it's directory within C:\websites\ - for example:

C:\websites\website_one\*.* (just the files, not the directory) - and put those files straight in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ - then open those files in notepad++.

It is extremely annoying to have to move the website I no longer want to work on for that day back to C:\websites\, and to move a different website into htdocs\ every time I want to work on a different website.

Could anyone help me with the standard way of structuring the directories of your local development sites?

I want to be able to access/work on my different projects more easily, and also be able to upload any of them for online testing and not have to change any links/includes because the directory structure doesn't match.

Locally, should I just replicate the web hosts directory structure in htdocs? For example:

htdocs\public_html\website_one

htdocs\public_html\website_two

Or something similar?

Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: Google for virtual hosts

Comment: Why don't you have multiple directories inside your htdocs? Then use virtual hosts to set up custom URLs for each of them, as @zerkms suggested

Comment: Thank you both I will look into this. Appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you work with Apache anyways, why not work with sub domains or url rewrites?

Heres a link to set up sub domains.
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?394472-Setting-up-Subdomains-on-Localhost-Apache

Each site can be in its own folder, do keep in mind that includes or links should be based on the root of the website, not the root of the webserver.